# Can't find android.support.design.widget.Snackbar in support design library

Tags: android, android-support-library

I develop own library module where I use `Snackbar`.

Here is my Gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'me.zhanghai.android.materialprogressbar:library:1.1.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
}
```

As you can see, I have added `import com.android.support:design:23.1.1`, but as result I get error:

> error: package android.support.design.R does not exist

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Indeed the import package you've entered in your block quote is incorrect. This is the correct path `import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar`

Comment: change your build tool version to 23.1.1

Comment: add, compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'

Comment: if you are migrating to Androidx then this might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/59115576/9699634

Answer (score 94):

You must add the design dependency in your gradle file (module app) according to

#### AndroidX build artifact

```
implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha06"
```

#### Old build artifact

```
implementation "com.android.support:design:28.0.0"
```

If you are using Support libraries, you can visit [Support Library Packages  |  Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages#design),  for the latest Design Support Library version. If you're new to AndroidX and want to use it, you can find [more information about migrating to the new dependencies here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate).

Source: http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html
(Scroll all the way down)

Comment: I've added compile `'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'` But it does not help. Is there any difference between the changed versions ?

Comment: Nothing significant code-wise, but I had many problems changing versions after a project starts, so I can only assume there are some other settings that need to be changed.

If you have to change the version, try starting a new project and importing all the code and assets.

Comment: if you use `android x` dependency so `implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-rc01"`

Comment: if you are migrating to Androidx then this might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/59115576/9699634

Answer (score 21):

I solved the problem now :)

1. Open [File] -> [Project Structure...]
2. Select [app] in the left pad
3. Select [Dependencies] in the right tabs
4. Click [+] button on the right side
5. Select [1 Library dependency]
6. Choose [com.android.support:design ~~]
7. Click [OK] button and so on

Result:  library added 
        in [Project's External Libraries]

------ edit -----------------------------------

You can also add this External library in build.gradle(Module:app)

press Alt+Enter in build.gradle(Module:app)

-> add library dependency

-> choose what you need

and press "Sync Now" positioned up right corner

Comment: if you are migrating to Androidx then this might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/59115576/9699634

Answer (score 11):

To get the the [**Snackbar**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/Snackbar.html) into our Android proyect just add the reference of support:design library inside the `build.gradle` file :

```
dependencies {
    ...
    ...
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'
}
```

Be sure to sync your project with the gradle files [image: sync gradle icon], this will fix your problem.

---

Your error message is:

> error: package android.support.design.R does not exist

be sure to have the correct import:

```
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
```

Answer (score 10):

If you are migrating to androidx then use

`com.google.android.material.R.id.snackbar_text`

instead of

`android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text`

Don't miss to import `import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;`

Also implement `implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha02"`

Answer (score 4):

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
```

set it in gradle.(module app)
its working for me in android studio and device with orio.

Answer (score 4):

After upgrading to androidx it will show error.You have to import this library

```
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;
```

```
 Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, R.string.Mapview, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
            View snackbarView = snackbar.getView();
            TextView textView = (TextView) snackbarView.findViewById(com.google.android.material.R.id.snackbar_text);
            textView.setMaxLines(5);
            snackbar.show();
```

Hope it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
dependencies {
 compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
 testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
 compile 'me.zhanghai.android.materialprogressbar:library:1.1.4'
 compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Dependencies may change with upgrading of android sdk versions, i am creating application in sdkversion 27. I have added the following dependency for snackbar.
 `implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'`

Answer (score 2):

Just type fully qualified class name **android.support.design.widget.SnackBar**
instead of just **SnackBar** at every occurrence . It solves the issue for me.

Comment: Solves my problem too.

Answer (score 0):

Remove Support v4 from your project and then add support design library.

Answer (score 0):

Use implementation "com.android.support:design:23.0.0"

or Change the Sdk to 28 and use
implementation "com.android.support:design:28.0.0"